# Is $f(x, y) = xy-2x-y$ an hyperbolic paraboloid?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix, parabolic-pde

so I solved the function, finding a hyperbolic paraboloid with a saddle point $xy-2x-y=-2$   at $(x, y)=(1, 2)$, with no global or local maxima and/or minima. But the answer sheet marks that it indeed has a minima at $(2, 1)$; and a saddle point at $(0, 0)$.

And doing the Hessian Matrix I've found only $-1$, with no variables attached to it.

As it is a hyperbolic paraboloid, I thought that it wouldn't have maxima and minima points, as spotted in the first place.

Is it possible for an hyperbolic paraboloid to have maxima and minima?

Comment: Based on what you posted, you are correct. Did you post the complete question? Were there any restrictions?

Comment: The equation in the body of the question is the union of the planes $x=1$ and $y=2$.

Comment: Yeah, it only asks me to determine the maxima and minima values and saddle points if they exist.

Comment: Here's a [3D plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrSyzSUK_QqVTX5ApQsFUoyMkvMU7RqNCq1DXSqtCt1FHQ0DXSMdFE0PkFicmZJZW2BnoWIC3aQD35mXkgTdEahjpGOrpGmrE6CsWZVam2pgY6Csn5OflFtkpFqSlKGMqNdAx1dI2xKa9MzcnJLwfqKM7IL9cI0AQAkHEt8g==&lang=sage) with x & y in [-2,4]. I marked the (1,2,-2) saddle point with a red dot, and the alleged minimum (2,1,-3) with a yellow dot. As you can see, it's definitely not a minimum.

Comment: @PM2Ring is the x and y in [-2, 4] part of the solution or just your pick to project the 2d plot? - thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes, it's just the range I chose for the plot. You can easily edit line 2 of the code to show a different region. In `plot3d(x*y-2*x-y, (-2,4), (-2,4), opacity=0.8)` the 1st range is for x, the 2nd for y.